# Use strong induction to prove that n is congruent.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need some hints on this question:

There are two players, Bill and Steve. Initially there is a pile of $n$ coins placed on a table. The players alternate turns, with Bill playing first. Each player, on his turn, removes either one or two coins from the pile. The player who takes the last coin wins. Use strong induction to prove that if n is congruent to 1 or 2 (mod 3) then Bill has a winning edge (he can win no matter what Steve does), and if $n$ is congruent to 0 (mod 3) then Steve has an edge.

Any ideas on where to begin?

Answer (score 1):

This game is sometimes known as [Nim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim).  At any rate, here's a hint:

Suppose it's Steve's turn with $3$ coins on the table.  If he takes $1$ coin, then Bill can take $2$ coins to win.  If he takes $2$ coins, Bill can take $1$ coin to win.  In this manner,  Bill can win no matter what Steve does, as long as he can bring the number of coins down to $3$.

So, if it's Bill's turn and there are $3+1 = 4$ or $3+2 = 5$ coins, then Bill can take $1$ or $2$ coins to put himself in a winning situation.

Now, suppose it's Steve's turn with $6$ coins on the table...

---

Here's what an inductive proof might look like:

**Base case:** If it's Bill's turn with $1$ or $2$ coins, then Bill can take the remaining coins in his next turn.  So, Bill can win no matter what Steve does in these cases.

**Inductive step:** Suppose that Bill can win no matter what Steve does if there are $3k+1$ or $3k + 2$ coins left for all integers $k$ from $0$ to $n$.

Now, suppose there are $3(n+1) + 1$ or $3(n+1) + 2$ coins left.  Then Bill can take either $1$ or $2$ coins so that there are $3(n+1)$ coins left.

When Steve takes his turn, he take $2$ or $1$ coins, leaving either $3n+1$ or $3n+2$ coins. By our inductive hypothesis, Bill can now win no matter what Steve does.

The conclusion follows.

Comment: So from my understanding, it has to do with whether if the n coins are odd or even?

Comment: The point is that as long as it's Steve's turn with $3n$ coins on the table, Bill will win.  If you're not seeing this, try playing the game.

Comment: I understand that part, but I don't understand how that is implemented through strong induction. What am I missing?

Comment: Your first comment makes it sound like you're missing something. What does "odd or even" have to do with this?

Comment: I just thought that since 5 coins are odd, then Bill has the advantage and if Steve's turn with 6 coins (which is even) then Steve has the advantage.

Comment: Not quite. If it's Steve's turn with $6$ coins, then either it will be Bill's turn with $5$ coins or Bill's turn with $4$ coins.  So, it would still be Bill's advantage.  In all of these situations, Bill has the advantage.

Comment: I still don't get how I turn this into strong induction.